# Browser Instrumentation

Tags: javascript, browser

I need to mimic the behavior of a browser. For Say I need to acess the DOM properties of a webpage (ex. Document.cookie or window.onblur etc) without loading a webpage in an actual browser and without interacting (ex. clicking button, putting mouse over a link etc) in the browser.

Infact, I am trying to do some thing where I have an imaginary  browser Object BROWSER. So, I can do :

```
BROWSER g = BROWSER.load('google.com');
g.document.cookie();
g.window.onblur();
```

I guess this is known as 'browser instrumentation'. How Can I do it ? Any ideas.. ?

Comment: What are you specifically trying to accomplish? If it's not running in an actual browser does it have to use javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably Selenium (http://seleniumhq.org/).  Although it does use a real browser (which is sort of necessary if you want to test things in a real browser environment), it will allow you to completely automate/control that browser to make it do whatever you want.  Using it you can write code like this:

```
# Pseudo-code to search for Selenium on Google
browser.open('www.google.com')
browser.findElementByCSS('#search').value('Selenium')
browser.findElementByCSS('#submitButton').click()
```

which sounds like what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks machineghost for the reply. Probably, this is something I am looking around...

Answer (score 2):

Is this something you're looking for? It's called [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

From the site:

> Full web stack, No browser required
>
> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit with JavaScript API. It has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.
>
> Run functional tests with frameworks such as Jasmine, QUnit or CasperJS.